# Cannot run Python3.6 in debugging mode in Visual Studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I am trying to run my Python program in debugging mode under Python3.6 environment in VS, yet everytime I endup with the error below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtH4W.png)

Which also generates the following message in the Output window:

```
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```

I have tried almost everything, from reinstalling VS and Python3.6 together, adding Python3.6 environemnt manually from VS, checking the contents of the registry files in regedit. None of them worked!

The issue does not occurr for other versions of Python. I was able to successfully install and run in Debug mode Pythons 3.9 and 3.11.1.

What could have caused the problem?

I have tried almost everything, from reinstalling VS and Python3.6 together, adding Python3.6 environemnt manually from VS, checking the contents of the registry files in regedit. None of them worked!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VS does not support Python 3.6 anymore - see [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7615).